# How to style NowPlayingView swiftui

Tags: swiftui, watchkit

I'm trying to set the background color for `NowPlayingView` instead of the basic blurred background that comes when implementing the view. I've tried setting the `foregroundColor`, `background` & even `accentColor` but none of these change any colors on the `NowPlayingView`. Is this something that's possible to do with the `NowPlayingView`?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/nowplayingview

```
NowPlayingView()
      .body.background(Color.red)
```

Comment: What is `NowPlayingView`? Would you provide code?

Comment: @Asperi It's a view that apple provides, here's the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/nowplayingview